# "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection" when calling https endpoint from Payara5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara, java-ee-8

I try to query an https endpoint using JavaEE8 from application deployed on Payara5 running on a docker container (based on Alpine Linux). The code below works fine from my developer machine, but from within the docker container I get the infamous `Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection`. Also I‘m working over VPN using a Cisco agent.

```
Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                                     .register(new Authenticator("",
                                                                 ""))
                                     .target("https://my-company-intranet.net")
                                     .path("resource/to/post")
                                     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                     .post(Entity.entity(vehicleConfiguration,
                                                         MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
```

What I tried up to now

- adding a custom SSLContext using `.sslContext()` on the `ClientBuilder`, where I set `TLSv1.2` or a general `HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = (hostname, sslSession) -> true``
- I set `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` in the `domain.xml`, which just shows me 
  that the handshake stops at `http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3), WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 228`
- `System.setProperty("https.nonProxyHosts","*.my-company-intranet.net");`

Java version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.9.0) (Alpine 8.181.13-r0)
```

**I suppose something with certificates, wrong Payara configuration or alike, but I can't understand where this is coming from... The error message does not make any sense to me in this context...**